# Online vs Offline Triplet Selection in FaceNet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision

I have been reading [FaceNet](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/app/1A_089.pdf). In the Triplet Selection section, it is written

> Generate triplets offline every n steps, using the most
> recent network checkpoint and computing the argmin
> and argmax on a subset of the data.

and

> Generate triplets online. This can be done by selecting the hard positive/negative exemplars from within a mini-batch.

The words "online" and "offline" make me puzzled. What do "online" and "offline" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too late but anyway.
Offline means you make your triplet first, and then make mini batches from those triplets while online means you make triplets after a mini batch of samples, and so in each mini batch training you have to go through the triplet selection for that mini batch.
Here is a good explanation provided by the following link.
[Triplet Loss](https://towardsdatascience.com/triplet-loss-advanced-intro-49a07b7d8905#:%7E:text=This%20is%20due%20to%20the,pairs%20are%20at%20that%20moment.)